# JQuery mobile disables links and forms

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, disabled-control

I've made page with sidebar, which can be hidden. I added JQ mobile becouse I need swipe event for handling it on mobile devices, but JQ mobile broke the page completely.

All forms are submitted by AJAX (I found event for forms and links in G Chrome- developers) and all links also tries to load content by AJAX.

Is there any way how to disable it for whole page (some global config, not just with data-ajax=”false” which doesn't work for me at all)?

Could anyone help me fixing that? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

After few hours browsing documentation, I've found, what I needed. I just needed to move config code before JQ Mobile script loading.

Now it works;

```
<script src="files/script/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
            $.extend($.mobile, {autoInitializePage: false});
        });
    </script>
<script src="files/script/lib/jquery-mobile.min.js"></script>
```